# Saving Image to SQLite NSUInteger Error

Tags: objective-c, image, sqlite, nsuinteger

I have been saving images to a sqlite database with no issues until I installed Xcode 5. Here is the line of code and the error. The error is pointing to the [dataForImage length].

Code:

```
NSData *dataForImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSitePhoto.image);
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 14, [dataForImage bytes], [dataForImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Error:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka
>   'unsigned long') to 'int'

Anyone else had this and know how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16918980/312312

Comment: -[NSData length] returns an NSUInteger, sqlite3_bind_blob takes an int