# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
-(void)bindStatement:(sqlite3_stmt *)statement withArg:(NSObject *)arg atIndex:(NSUInteger)argIndex
{
    if ([arg isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        sqlite3_bind_null(statement, argIndex);//Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'
    } else if ([arg isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSNumber *numberArg = (NSNumber *)arg;
        const char *numberType = [numberArg objCType];
        if (strcmp(numberType, @encode(int)) == 0) {
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, argIndex, [numberArg integerValue]);
        } else if (strcmp(numberType, @encode(long long int)) == 0) {
            sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, argIndex, [numberArg longLongValue]);
        } else if (strcmp(numberType, @encode(double)) == 0) {
            sqlite3_bind_double(statement, argIndex, [numberArg doubleValue]);
        } else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, argIndex, [[arg description] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
```

Comment: That's Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [objective c implicit conversion loses integer precision 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918826/objective-c-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision-nsuinteger-aka-unsig).

Answer (score 0):

The `index` parameter of all of the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions expect its datatype to be `int`, not `NSUInteger`.

The simplest solution is to change the datatype of your `argIndex` parameter from `NSUInteger` to `int`. Or convert `argIndex` to an `int` value when using it with the calls to the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

It's always best to use the proper datatype for a given variable.