# How to fix Implicit conversion loses integer precision warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nscalendar

I am using this code to encode and decode `NSCalenderUnit`

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];

    NSNumber *boxed = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:self.myNSCalendarUnit];
    [encoder encodeObject:boxed forKey:@"myNSCalendarUnit"];
    // ...

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSNumber *boxed = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myNSCalendarUnit"];
        _myNSCalendarUnit = [boxed unsignedLongLongValue];
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I am getting this warning

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long long' to
>   'NSCalendarUnit' (aka 'enum NSCalendarUnit')

How to correct code to remove this warning?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the description type of NSCalendarUnit

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSCalendarUnit)
```

You should change to `_myNSCalendarUnit = [boxed unsignedIntegerValue]` for conform type. The `long long` is defined by 64-bit, but NSUInteger is not ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918826/objective-c-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision-nsuinteger-aka-unsig?rq=1)). And when create boxed, you should use with the same datatype `NSNumber *boxed = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:self.myNSCalendarUnit];`

Comment: but I used numberWithUnsignedLong to convert into NSNumber... will converting to unsignedIntegerValue can impact in ay way?

Comment: The most appropriate way is you create [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:self.myNSCalendarUnit];` with original type of NSCalendar (NSUInteger). It should not lost data of any case. Further, in your current code, you create with `unsignedLong` but get with `unsignedLongLong`, it is not approciate.