# Warning Compiler Flag

Tags: xcode, clang

I'm trying to find the flag to disable this warning when building C with Xcode:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision

The UI doesn't seem to show which warning flag this is related to:

[image: UI]

Is there a way to find the respective flag in the UI?

Comment: Why not just fix the warning?

Comment: @StephenNewell looks like the OP doesn't own this code

Comment: Correct - I don't own the code, so I just want to mute the warnings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28064016/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `-Wno-conversion` flag was what I was looking for.